# Laravel setup, trying to have cronjob call a function within php laravel file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, cron, laravel-5

### Original Post

Good evening folks. I have a laravel setup and I'm trying to have a cronjob execute a php function to a file within the laravel project directory.

I am getting class and name space errors when I try to do something like this:

```
<?php
require_once('../laravel/app/Http/Controllers/NotificationsController.php');
```

and then calling the `processQueuedNotifications()` function.

This of course gives me errors, **what is the correct way to call my function within the laravel directory?** I need to call this function as this function has all the correct namespaces and extended controllers necessary to execute the function properly.

---

### Update 1:

Thanks to @michael, I've been made aware of a component in Laravel called `commands`.

So I ran this code:
`php artisan make:console processQueuedNotifications`
and it created some files in the console directory.

Currently exploring on what to do next.

1. After checking out the `Event`s class which the `kernel.php` file makes use of, I noticed that this class provides an easy to use interface for me to create cron jobs on the fly. Am I correct in think so?
2. I notice there is not function to run a cron job every minute, is it safe to edit the `Events` class file without it being overwritten by future `make:console` commands, or laravel updates?
3. I saw this code in the `kernel.php` file:

   ```
   $schedule->command('inspire')
                    ->hourly();
   ```

So is this the place you wanted me to add my function? as I notice that the inspire function is something automatically created for me to understand what's going on?

So I would write,

```
$schedule->command('processQueuedNotifications')
                 ->everyMinute();
//Providing it's safe to edit the Event's class or figure out a clean way of doing so without my code being deleted in the future on Laravel updates.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very convenient way is to use laravels console component. You can create a new command by issuing

```
php artisan make:console
```

And find it thereafter in your `app/console` directory. Make sure to enable the command in the Kernel.php file once created.

Simply call your class or whatever you want to run via cron from inside the command. The console command itself is callable via cli just as you would run one of laravels `php artisan ...` commands. You can set this in the file created for you. For example, you can then call the file from everywhere you want with

```
/usr/bin/php /path/to/file/artisan my:command
```

You can set options and arguments if you need to.

Here's the documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/commands / http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html

There's an array in `kernel.php` you need to register your class (include the namespace) in. After that it is callable via cli.  For a start, have a look on arguments and options you can initialize in case you need to make different requests on your controller class. (The filename you have chosen for your console command, is an argument. You can make them required or optional for your own commands. )

Within your file, you can create them by simply creating an array in the appropriate method with these values:

```
 [$name, $mode, $description, $defaultValue]
```

have a look at the docs or Jeffrey's laracasts, they are very good.

To only call your class from the console command, it's enough to name your command in the above section of the file and call you controller like

```
(new namespace\controller)->method();
```

Comment: Hey michael, thanks for the swift response. I didn't know about this feature of Laravel. I'm new to Laravel transitioning from the Slim php framework. What other must-knows are there about laravel? Will completing the laravel fundamentals course on laracasts cover commands? (just wondering if I had completed the course whether I would have been able to answer my own question lol)

Comment: There's even a 4 or 5 lesson course about console commands on laracasts, I've seen it some time ago. Well, I really like the upcoming broadcasting events. Taylor Otwell published a video about those lately.

Comment: that looks very interesting. I'm looking to get into socket integration too. I hope the next update comes out soon (in the comments he talks about being able to broadcast events to specific users, that would be awesome, especially if it's made very easy to interact with).

Anyway..

Comment: Could you please take a look at **update 1**, Michael?

Comment: Hey buddy, your url on laravel/commands helped a tonne! I have a cron job running my custom code! fantastic! what's exciting is that I can even run my command from CLI! I've learned a lot. Cheers buddy. I was going to give a more detail post on how to achieve what I did from beginning to end since I feel it may help someone else but figured i'd give you the marked answer for now!

Answer (score 1):

What you can do in your code, after your update, 2 choices :

1. Dispatching directly the command from your code using the Bus facade

first import it using the 
`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus;`

then in your code

```
Bus::dispatchNow(new YourCommandClass);
```

(don't forget to import your command class)

2. Dispatch it for queue process using the same bus facade:

(still importing the same way)

```
Bus::dispatch(new YourCommandClass);
```

(Note that in that case, you'll need to have the following command run by your cron job :

```
php artisan queue:listen
```

it can handle several options such as the --tries=X where is is the number of tries etc

Generally speaking, you can get more info from commands typing php artisan my:command -h